# My contract factory is deploying, but fails to deploy the child contract

Tags: solidity

I am using Remix to build a pretty standard contract factory, code below:

Deploying the factory works fine, but when I try to access the createContract() function, I get an error: "VM error: revert".

I am sending 10001 Wei and can see that as the msg.value in the debug, but it's not even stepping into the constructor that I can see.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

contract MediaContractFactory {
    address [] public deployedContracts;
    event Received(address, uint);

    function createContract(uint deploymentPrice, uint expiration, string memory tasking, string memory formatting) public{
          address newContract =  address(new MediaContract(deploymentPrice, expiration, tasking, formatting, payable(msg.sender)));
          deployedContracts.push(newContract);
    }

    function getDeployedContracts() public view returns (address [] memory){
        return deployedContracts;
    }

    receive() external payable {
        emit Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }
}

contract MediaContract {
    address payable public customer ;
    address payable public platform;
    address payable public reporter;
    address public contractAddress;
    uint public contractPrice;
    uint public platformFee;
    struct Coordinate {
        uint256 lat;
        uint256 long;
    }
    string public task;
    string public format;
    uint public created;
    uint public expires;
    string public status;
    Coordinate[] public coordinates;
    string[] public mediaAddresses;
    event Received(address, uint);

    constructor (uint deploymentPrice, uint expiration, string memory tasking, string memory formatting, address payable newCustomer) payable{
        require(msg.value >= deploymentPrice);
        customer = newCustomer;
        contractPrice =  address(this).balance * 95 / 100;
        platformFee = address(this).balance * 5 / 100;
        created = block.timestamp;
        expires = expiration;
        task = tasking;
        format = formatting;
        status = 'open';
        contractAddress = address(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply missing the `payable` keyword in `createContract` function, and to forward `msg.value` to the child contract like this:

```
    function createContract(...) public payable {   // added payable here
          address newContract =  address(new MediaContract{value: msg.value}(...));  // added {value: msg.value} here
          deployedContracts.push(newContract);
    }
```

Comment: That makes sense, but with these changes, it won't even deploy.

Comment: Does it show an error?

Comment: [vm]from: 0x5B3...eddC4to: MediaContractFactory.(constructor)value: 1000 weidata: 0x608...70033logs: 0hash: 0x2ef...6e3e7
status false Transaction mined but execution failed
transaction hash 0x2ef49682c82fcf04cc2c27cdc5b8bfee22145fd734c58e1cec9530d817b6e3e7
from 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4
to MediaContractFactory.(constructor)
gas 3000000 gas
transaction cost 215257 gas 
execution cost 215257 gas 
input 0x608...70033
decoded input {}
decoded output  - 
logs []
val 1000 wei
creation of MediaContractFactory errored: VM error: revert.

Comment: It looks like you used `msg.value > 0` during the deployment. It should be 0.

Comment: But I want the contract to be funded on creation.

Comment: And why should it fail? You can see in the error message that the value is 1000 wei.

Comment: If you want to fund the Factory on creation you need to have the constructor payable, so add this `constructor() payable {}`.